# SwiftUI ColorPicker cause pop to root view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I have this weird issue. When I click the ColorPicker, the view dismissed and pop back to the root view. I have attach a screen record below. Anyone have idea how to fix this issue?

The code run on simulator ios 15.2

[See screen record here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7ALj.gif)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                HomePageView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Home", systemImage: "circle.grid.cross.fill")
                    }
              
                ProfileView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.fill")
                    }
            }
            .background(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

struct HomePageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Home View")
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            ColorPickerView()
        } label: {
            Text("Color Picker View")
        }
    }
}

struct ColorPickerView: View {
    @State var bgColor = Color.blue
    var body: some View {
        ColorPicker("Pick color", selection: self.$bgColor)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the NavigationView in each tab instead of outside the tabview

Comment: works well for me, on macos 12.3-beta, using xcode 13.3-beta, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. 
You could try adding: `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to the `NavigationView` or use @lorem ipsum suggestion.

Comment: `TabViews` are an exception to the rule of putting the `NavigationView` at the top level. It has to go inside the tab item views.

Comment: Thank you guys. @loremipsum's solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationView` in each tab instead of outside the `TabView`

Comment: Hi @loremipsum, so after I put the NavigationView inside each tab item, the bottom tab bar always appear inside each detailed view. Do you know how to hide it?

Comment: @yang1818 There are workarounds out there for hiding like your original question and the other solutions in the comments but that behavior goes against apple [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/) there is no perfect solution to hiding the tabbar as far as I know. You always give something up.

Answer (score 0):

New suggestion: Use NavigationStack in iOS16 to overcome the issue of popping to the previous or sometimes to the root view.